# How to share current activity on facebook?

Tags: android

I want to share test time on facebook from the activity using fb share button.I have already searched so many quotes in Google but not able to do that.  I have also attached app activity url. In this activity I want to share on facebook from congratulation to investigation time. My problem not able to get screen shot at a time of sharing and getting notification image uploading and share failed. Any ideas?

```
App Activity url - https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7qIv.png


// code what I have tried?

   // fb share button

 fb_share_btn.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener ( ) {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Bitmap bitmap = takeScreenshot();
                saveBitmap(bitmap);
                shareIt();
            }
        });
    }

// logic 

 public void saveBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
//        imagePath = new File (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/screenshot.png");
        ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper (getApplicationContext());
        File directory = cw.getDir("imageDir", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        imagePath = new File(directory,"/screenshot.png");

        //Log.i ("Message","Testingabc"+imagePath);
        FileOutputStream fos;
        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream (imagePath);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e("GREC", e.getMessage(), e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("GREC", e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }
    private void shareIt() {
        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(imagePath);
        Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sharingIntent.setType("image/*");
        String shareBody = "In Tweecher, My highest score with screen shot";
        sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "My Tweecher score");
        sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
        sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);

        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried something and got problem? And if you do, would you please post what have you tried?

Or are you still wondering how to do that?

Comment: @YosiPramajaya, Bro I have edited my code. Please help me. I have also added actvity url which i want to share. please read my query again.